# How to prepend pattern like '.*' to command-line arguments for user-commands

Tags: vim, neovim

I'd like to prefix a pattern like `.*` to the user defined command's argument so that the user doesn't have to enter that everytime.

Here's a minimal working example to reproduce the issue:

```
fun Fruits(A, L, P)
  let l:valid_fruits = ['apple', 'peach', 'orange', 'mango', 'blackberry', 'strawberry', 'blueberry']

  let l:filtered_fruits = filter(l:valid_fruits, { idx, val -> val =~ a:A })

  return join(l:filtered_fruits, "\n")
endf
command! -complete=custom,Fruits -nargs=1 Fruits :echom(<f-args>)
```

With this I can type `:Fruits b` and hit Tab to show completion options of `blackberry` and `blueberry`, all good. But I want a behavior where I do `:Fruits berry` and hit tab to show `blackberry` and `blueberry` and `strawberry`. One way to get this behavior is by prefixing `.*` in the command-line argument like so: `:Fruits .*berry`.

So, naively I went and updated my filtering like to below:

```
let l:filtered_fruits = filter(l:valid_fruits, { idx, val -> val =~ '.*'.a:A })
```

But this wouldn't work and i couldn't fully understand why, I believe I am missing something small (& probably silly), but can someone please point out?

Comment: That worked, thanks! :) Can you add that as an answer, I'll accept it. Follow-up question on the efficiency part, can you provide more information on this, the help for custom only says `its probably more efficient in most cases` I'd like the custom filtering to be as efficient as possible!